# why cant I compare two id's in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, compare

I tried to compare two ids and get some result.it works for other strings.but not for this.
I tried like this.

```
var neededData = mainFaires.Where(c => c.trimacid == passId );
```

in here `passId= OX20160330HAVHAV`

and in the `mainFaires` list, in somewhere it includes this `id`.but it didn't give the result.I found in here

```
var x = mainFaires.ElementAt(27261);
```

this list include the same `id`.but didn't give result.I can't think why.

Comment: Does using First() instead of ElementAt give you a result? If you are using LINQ to SQL, this can't be translated to SQL whereas First() can translate to TOP 1

Comment: Have you checked the case of the Id's are the same.

Answer (score 0):

ElementAt is find the position.

You should use select to find the records

```
var x = mainFaires.Select(o => o.trimacid == 27261);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.ToList()` `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` to actually commit the query and get a result. Your code only defined the query, but didn't actually submit it to the data collection.

If you expect only one item as a result, you're code should look like this:

```
var neededData = mainFaires.Where(c => c.trimacid == passId ).FirstOrDefault();
```

If there was no item found, neededData would be NULL or whatever the default value is. You may also check the Documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx